# error when import torch-geometric module full path with constructor syntax required

Tags: import, torch

I get the following error when I try to import torch-vision

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\...site-packages\torch_sparse\_convert_cuda.pyd' (or one of its 
dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

however the '_convert_cuda.pyd' file does exist in the mentioned path

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of editing an old question.

Comment: I am only able to edit old question since I am banned to ask new ones

Comment: Then you need to work on editing your questions answer to _improve_ them, not change them into new ones.

Comment: do you mean  answers or questions ?

Comment: Note that [deleting poorly-received questions will not affect your question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: Questions, sorry.

Comment: Anyway, the question you just edited this one to would be closed immediately as "opinion-based".